# Undefined dictionary in Info.plist

Tags: info.plist

> Sep  4 18:26:17 MacBook-Pro-77 com.apple.dt.Xcode[315] :
>   installApplication:withOptions:error:: Error
>   Domain=IXUserPresentableErrorDomain Code=1 "This app could not be
>   installed at this time." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=This app
>   could not be installed at this time., NSUnderlyingError=0x7fd558a69980
>   {Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=39 "Appex bundle at
>   /Users/mrinmaykalita/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4E1C6B5B-2711-47ED-B8B6-27DA419E4609/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.9nyJrs/extracted/Beam.app/Watch/Beam
>   Watch.app/PlugIns/Beam Watch Extension.appex with id
>   com.bpl.Beam.watchkitapp.watchkitextension does not define an
>   NSExtension dictionary in its Info.plist"
>   UserInfo={LegacyErrorString=AppexBundleMissingNSExtensionDict,
>   FunctionName=-[MIPluginKitPluginBundle overlaidInfoPlistWithError:],
>   SourceFileLine=213, NSLocalizedDescription=Appex bundle at
>   /Users/mrinmaykalita/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4E1C6B5B-2711-47ED-B8B6-27DA419E4609/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.9nyJrs/extracted/Beam.app/Watch/Beam
>   Watch.app/PlugIns/Beam Watch Extension.appex with id
>   com.bpl.Beam.watchkitapp.watchkitextension does not define an
>   NSExtension dictionary in its Info.plist}}}

In the above output from `CoreSimlutor.log`; why is `com.apple.mobile.installd.staging` referred to when that folder does not exist or get created in running.

Any quick workouts kindly please?

I checked that the key exists in Info.plist for

```
<dict>
  <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
  <dict>
    <key>WKAppBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.bpl.Beam.watchkitapp</string>
  </dict>
  <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
  <string>com.apple.watchkit</string>
</dict>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after changing location of `Info.plist` file for app/WatchKit extension or WatchKit app. Other reason may be just renamed folder for WatchKit app or extension.

You have to clean all targets including main application, extensions and WatchKit app. I had to perform clean using `Cmd+Shift+K` for each target once changing targets in drop down in Xcode one after another.